# How to find UNCOUNTABLE disjoint balls in this metric space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space consisting of infinitely many elements and $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $X$ such that $\mu(B)$ is positive on any metric ball. Show that $L^\infty(\mu)$ is non-separable.

I want to find a sequence of uncountable elements in $L^\infty(\mu)$ with any two distinct elements have a uniform positive distance.In particular, if there exist a set of uncountable disjoint balls $\{B_r(x) \}$, I consider their characteristic function and the problem follows. However, I stuck in here. Any help is appreciated .Thanks.

Comment: You can in general not find an uncountable family of disjoint balls. Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$, every ball contains a rational point, and there are only countably many rational points.

Comment: If you have just infinitely many disjoint balls, then you can, for each subset of the balls, consider the characteristic function of their union. You still get the distances between them equal to $1$. There are uncountably many subsets of the infinite set of ball.

Comment: To construct infinitely many disjoint balls show that you can get one ball that has infinitely many of the elements of $X$ in its complement. Then assume that you already have $n$ disjoint balls with infinitely many elements of $X$ outside and prove that you can add one more to the collection.

Comment: @DanielFischer you say _"in general"_  you cannot, which suggests there are maybe some cases where you can. But your argument seems pretty convincing to me for all cases. Are there any exceptions? If so, got an example? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnForkosh In other metric spaces you can. For example, if $X$ is uncountable with the metric in which the distance between different points is $1$ you can enclose each point in a ball of radius $1/2$.

Comment: @JohnForkosh If $X$ is an uncountable discrete space, then you have uncountable families of disjoint balls. Or take $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$. The balls $B_{1/3}(\chi_A)$ for $A \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ are disjoint.

Comment: @DanielFischer and (at)conditionalMethod Thanks. I guess I was too much thinking of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, you are right. thanks. It is enough to consider how to find countable infinitely many balls. Then consider the characteristic functions of their power set.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Many thanks for your suggestion. I has some confusion with your later answer for constructing infinitely many disjoint balls. Can you give more details?

Comment: For the first ball, take two points of $X$, $a\neq b$. Consider the ball with center $a$ and radius $d(a,b)/2$. If there are infinitely many points outside of it you are done. If not, take the ball of center $b$ and radius $d(a,b)/4$.

Comment: When you have already constructed $n$ disjoint balls with centers $a_1,...,a_n$ and radius $r_1,...,r_n$ such that outside their union there are infinitely many points, let $a\neq b$ be two different points outside of all the balls. Consider the ball with centers $a$ and radius $R=\min_{1\leq k\leq n}(d(a,a_k), d(a,b))/2$. If this ball (joined with the previous $n$) also leaves infinitely many points outside, then take it. If not, look at the ball with center $b$ and radius $R/2$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you very much! I totally understand this idea you offered.